# GIT - git-add error (Bad File Number)

Tags: git, git-add

I'm using Git to create a backup system.

I've just created the directory and initialized git on it.

```
git init
```

When I tried to add the untracked files to the stage with

```
git add -u *.pdf
```

I get this response error:

> sh.exe": /bin/git: Bad file number

As additional information, I have a list of ~4500 untracked files and if I try to add the files one by one, I don't get any error response and the files are sent to the stage.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and why it happens? I need to add all these untracked files, but I don't want to do that in a "monkey job" way, adding one by one.

Comment: I actually had made a dumb mistake. I'd written the git-add command without surrounding the wildcard with single quotes. And like @GoZoner said, I had misunderstood the meaning of the option '-u'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want '-u' as it will only add files that you are already tracking.  After a `git init` you are not tracking anything yet. From the documentation:

> -u, --update: Only match  against already tracked files in the index rather than the working tree. That means that it will never
>   stage new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of
>   tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the
>   corresponding files in the working tree have been removed.

Use `-A` (or `--all`) instead.

For your specific problem, when you write '*.pdf' the shell expands that into 4500 files.  That large number of files probably overflows the shell command line input buffer; which leads to the error.   You could do a few things:

```
git add -A               # adds everything at once
```

or

```
for file in *.pdf; do git add -A $file; done    # add files one by one
```

Both of these suggestions will avoid the command line issue; the first is preferred.

Comment: I actually had made a dumb mistake. I'd written the git-add command without surrounding the wildcard with single quotes. The problem was not overflow ¬¬.

But your explanation was very helpful!

I'm a newbie on Git. Sorry for wasting your time. I've just started to read and learn about it, today (http://git-scm.com/book/en/)

Many thanks from Brazil!

Comment: I can't add an up-vote, I don't have enough reputation. I need at least 15 points. But when i get them, I return here and give you the vote.

Thanks

Comment: If you pass `*.pdf` to `git add` then git will expand the `*` and won't overflow.  If you skip the quotes, then the shell will expand `*` and overflow.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by saying "expand"?

Comment: 'Expand' means replacing '*.pdf' with all the matching files, like 'foo.pdf bar.pdf ...'